# pioneer 3dx simulation using rviz and stage

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, p2os, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I installed ROS on ubuntu 10.10 and I'm trying to simulate a pioneer robot on rviz. I have the usc p2os package and I'm trying to use the pioneer3dx.urdf for the robot simulation. The robot is recognised by rviz but the left, right wheels and hubcaps are not being recognised. I'm getting "no transform from [/...] to [/odom] error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Vinay

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9284/pioneer-3dx-simulation-using-rviz-and-stage/) by [vprasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/233/vprasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz listens for TF messages, by default on topic /tf.  That is the only way it knows where each part of the robot is relative to other parts of the robot.

On my (simulated) system, /tf is published by nodes amcl, robot_pose_ekf, robot_state_publisher, and gazebo.  Perhaps you need to run more nodes to fill in the missing TF frames.

If nothing is filling in the /odom frame, you can try setting the "fixed frame" in RViz to /map or /base_footprint.  For that matter, in my system I don't have a frame called /odom, I only have /odom_combined.  Maybe that is the problem?

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2